# Create a variable width rolling window over an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have time series data in an IEnumerable, with non even sampling ( i.e i may have 5 samples in first 10 seconds,  then ten in the next ten seconds etc)

I want to create a rolling mean, max, and min over a 30 second rolling window

I believe that skip enumerates from the beginning each time.

Is it possible to get the result from skip and use it again without calling it?

Are copyable iterators possible in c#, as I would like to have a beginwindow and endwindow iterator that I then enumerate between, meaning that I don't have to iterate from the beginning each time,

my code currently works and looks line this

```
class Data
{
    float Value;
    DateTime Time;
};



BufferData = new IEnumerable<...>
int index = 0;
TimeSpan windowWidth = new TimeSpan(0,0,30);
DateTime currentStart;
while (index < BufferData.Count)
{
    currentStart = BufferData.Skip(index).First().Time;
    var window = BufferData.Skip(index).TakeWhile(x => x.Time<= currentStart + windowWidth);

    DateTime centre = currentStart + new TimeSpan((window.Last().Time- currentStart).Ticks / 2);
    float min = window.Min(x => x.Value);
    float max = window.Max(x => x.Value);
    ++index;
}
```

Comment: A few questions: How large is your data set? How important is performance? To clarify, you want all the samples in a time window regardless of whether that is zero or 1,000 right?

Comment: the dataset could be millions of items, not necessarily all in memory at once. good performance is required, I want all samples in a window regardless of how many samples. ( if there are no samples in a window  don't need a new one generated

Comment: On a phone at the moment so hard to show a code example, but could you use a select to get the values in the range instead of skip, then take your min, max, and mean from that?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that illustrates your question, along with a clear explanation of what that code does and what you want it to do instead, it's difficult if not impossible to understand the question.

Comment: That said, if what you're trying to do is generate _multiple_ such "windows", it seems to me you should just enumerate the entire data set once, start generating the mean/max/min values at the 30th sample, and then with each successive sample, add its value while subtracting the value of the sample(s) older than 30 seconds prior. Then you only need to maintain in memory 30 seconds worth of samples.

Comment: It sounds like from your question that you want to generate a sliding window of 30 seconds worth of data stepping forward in 10 second increments. Is that the idea? Or do you just want to group your data so that for every value added you output that value plus any others that were produced in the last 30 seconds?

Comment: Also, what is the source of your data? Is it purely historical (i.e. tons of data that you're loading from disk or something)? Or is it from a live source (i.e. stock market feed)?

Comment: Does that mean it is required that I create a second list of all the values in the window and add remove appropriately? or can I somehow keep a "Pointer" to the beginning sample in the window and restart an enumeration from there each time I need to?

Comment: @user2258296 - You need to use the `@`-username notation to show who you are replying to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework team's "Interactive Extensions" (NuGet "Ix-Main") then this is a fairly straight-forward solution:

```
var windows =
    BufferData
        .Scan(new List<Data>(), (accumulator, item) =>
            accumulator
                .Where(x => x.Time.AddSeconds(30.0) >= item.Time)
                .Concat(new[] { item })
                .ToList())
        .Select(xs => new
        {
            Centre = xs.First().Time.AddSeconds(
                xs.Last().Time.Subtract(xs.First().Time).TotalSeconds / 2.0),
            Max = xs.Max(x => x.Value),
            Mix = xs.Min(x => x.Value),
        });
```

The scan operator uses and accumulator like the standard `.Aggregate` operator, but produces a value for each input.

This should be the same result as your current code.

It also only iterates the original source once (although there are multiple iterations within the 30 second window).

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking this could get huge, because he mentioned potentially millions of samples... but since Data is a reference type, we're actually only talking about potentially millions of references, which might be better. I think my solution is likely to be faster because I don't try to preserve the whole window and avoid re-iterating it in most cases, but this, well, actually preserves the entire Window in each sample if you need it. Also... I remembered MoreLINQ, but hadn't seen it was now MS-maintained in "Interactive  Extensions". That's cool.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Thanks. What would be cooler is if the OP can shed some light on the source of the data. If this can be turned into an Reactive Extensions observable it'll be far more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - As @PeterDuniho points out, this is not really a "rolling average". It doesn't recalculate with each new item added. It just provides a snapshot of statistics every 30 seconds (or whatever the `WindowWidth` is set to). I'll leave this answer for now in case it might be useful, but it's not really what was asked for.

---

I believe the following solution should perform quite quickly for large data sets (it should be O(n)). As a proof of concept, I ran this test on a 1 million item list, and it completed in 0.782 seconds in LINQPad 4 (on a laptop that is definitely not state of the art).

```
public IEnumerable<Stats> CalculateStats(
    List<Data> bufferData,
    DateTime startTime,
    TimeSpan windowWidth)
{
    var finishTime = bufferData.Last().Time;
    return bufferData
        .Select(x => new
        { 
            x.Value,
            WindowIndex = GetWindowIndex(x.Time, startTime, windowWidth)
        })
        .GroupBy(
            x => x.WindowIndex,
            (i, items) => new Stats
            { 
                StartTime = GetWindowTime(startTime, windowWidth, i),
                FinishTime = GetWindowTime(startTime, windowWidth, i + 1),
                Mean = (float)items.Average(x => x.Value),
                Max = (float)items.Max(x => x.Value),
                Min = (float)items.Min(x => x.Value)
            });
}

private int GetWindowIndex(DateTime time, DateTime startTime, TimeSpan windowWidth)
{
    var timeSinceStart = time - startTime;
    var secondsSinceStart = timeSinceStart.TotalSeconds;
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(secondsSinceStart / windowWidth.TotalSeconds);
}

private DateTime GetWindowTime(DateTime startTime, TimeSpan windowWidth, int windowIndex)
{
    return startTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(windowWidth.TotalSeconds * windowIndex);
}

public class Stats
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; }
    public float Mean { get; set; }
    public float Max { get; set; }
    public float Min { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The above appears to break the data into 30 second discontiguous "chunks". It's not clear at all to me that that's what the OP wants. "Rolling" usually means the window is a fixed width, but the start/end positions change with each new sample, not at fixed time intervals.

Comment: See my comment above, on the question. I'm not 100% sure I do understand the question, but I did provide some advice based on what I'm _guessing_ is the question. If you want to put the effort into it, you should be able to use that advice to provide what would likely be a more appropriate solution (I won't personally, because I don't put significant time into questions I'm not 100% sure I understand). Such a solution would also be O(n), and in practice would probably be a bit faster, as the dictionary costs more to maintain than the queue my suggestion would require.

Comment: At this point, I'll wait and see what the OP says. I added a disclaimer to my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this completely linearly, but at least whatever reiteraton only ocurrs inside the window, instead of over the whole dataset. This method provides all rolling (overlapped) windows of data samples within 30 seconds from eachother.

You can either have it as an Extension Method, or just a regular method. I've used an extension method for simplicity of use.

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Windows<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, DateTime> selector, TimeSpan span) {
    var enumerator = self.GetEnumerator();
    var samples = new List<T>();
    var start = DateTime.MinValue;

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var end = selector(enumerator.Current);
        if (end > start + span) {
            start = end - span;
        }
        samples = samples.SkipWhile(i => selector(i) < start).ToList();
        samples.Add(enumerator.Current);
        yield return samples;
    }
}
```

**Usage example:** Rolling average<sup>1</sup> over 30 seconds.

```
var rollingAverages = BufferData
    .Windows(d => d.Time, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))
    .Select(win => win.Average());
```

This works by treating the current element as the end of the window, so the window starts smaller than the given span, but grows over time up to that maximum.

- Initialize a empty sample container
- For each item of the dataset:

  - Set the window end to the current item's time.
  - If possible, grow the time range of the window.
  - Remove outdated items from sample container
  - Add current item to samples
  - **Yield sample container**

<sup>1</sup>: My statistic terms in English are a bit rusty, maybe this is a rolling mean?

Comment: _"whatever reiteraton only ocurrs inside the window"_ -- so, not quite O(n^2), but still O(m*n), which isn't great either. It also require iterating each window's samples _again_ just to calculate the mean/min/max. The above would be improved if you'd use a `Queue<T>` to store the window's samples (you can use `Peek()` to determine how many samples to remove, if any, with each new input sample), and keep running totals, to which you add new the sample value and from which you subtract any removed samples' value, before computing the mean/min/max to be returned.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're correct about the complexity, but I hope that the OP can move on from here. I've restricted myself to answering the question in a straightforward manner since I don't have time for complete scrutiny. Feel free to post an answer based on those suggestions, I would upvote it!

Comment: Also, there is only one iteration on the samples container. Seeing that it uses lazy evaluation, it is possible to note that the `SkipWhile` and `Concat` will be applied during the user iteration (e.g. `Average`).

Comment: How do you keep running totals of min or max, without reiterating the current window once the last value that was min or max goes out of scope of the window? I can understand the rolling mean.

Comment: I do like this answer because it gives me only one iteration of the whole dataset, whilst allowing me control over the window iteration, just testing it now.

Comment: _"there is only one iteration on the samples container"_ -- sort of. You need to remember that each "container" still references all of the earlier ones, and evaluating the `Skip()` requires evaluating all of the prior `Skip()` calls as well. Especially given the GC load you cause creating new one-element arrays each iteration, I think you might be better off materializing the concatenated samples sequence with each iteration.

Comment: (in fact, I retract my earlier assessment that the solution isn't O(n^2). I had only skimmed the code and had assumed you were in fact materializing each iterated sequence of samples. Since you're not, you _are_ in fact O(n^2) here instead of only O(m*n)).

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are correct. I orignally used the `List` interface to add the item, but then it would be required to reiterate the previous samples to re-materialize a list without the outdated elements. I haven't done any performance measurements, to be honest.

Comment: For future reference: I have changed the method to materialize the list every iteration, based on Peter's observations.

Answer (score 0):

Using queue you can minimize the number of memory allocations:

```
static IEnumerable<TimeSample> TimeRollingWindow (IEnumerable<Data> data, TimeSpan interval)
{


    Queue<Data> buffer = new Queue<Data>();

    foreach(var item in data) 
    {
        buffer.Enqueue(item);

        // Remove the old data
        while (buffer.Count > 0 && (item.Time - buffer.Peek().Time > interval))
        {
            buffer.Dequeue();
        }

        float max = float.MinValue;
        float min = float.MaxValue;
        double sum = 0;

        foreach(var h in buffer)
        {
            sum += h.Value;
            max = Math.Max(max, h.Value);
            min = Math.Min(min, h.Value);
        }

        // spit it out
        yield return new TimeSample(buffer.Peek().Time, item.Time, min, max, (float)(sum / buffer.Count));
    }
}


class TimeSample 
{
    public TimeSample(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime,  float min, float max, float mean)
    {
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
        Mean = mean;
    }

    public readonly DateTime StartTime;
    public readonly DateTime EndTime;

    public readonly float Min;
    public readonly float Max;
    public readonly float Mean;
}

class Data
{
    public Data(DateTime time, float value)
    {
        Time = time;
        Value = value;
    }
    public readonly DateTime Time;
    public readonly float Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/). It will allow you to [compute running totals](http://markheath.net/post/running-totals-linq-scan) and averages by writing [accumulator functions](http://seankerwin.org/archives/2008/12/generic_accumulators_in_c.shtml).

The trick for any "rolling window" kind of aggregation is simply to write an accumulator function that retains values from the sequence in a queue buffer as long as they remain in the desired window range. Sequence elements are dequeued from the buffer when they no longer meet the range criteria and their values are removed (de-accumulated) from any aggregates or totals.

Before I get into any code, I need to put out a disclaimer that everything below is typed directly into the reply window, meaning it probably won't even compile. The general concept is sound, but that's about as much as I can vouch for.

That out of the way, and using your `Data` class and `BufferData` seed along with the `.Scan()` function from MoreLINQ:

```
//First we need a type to hold the results:
class Result
{
   double min;
   double max;
   DateTime first; //needed for centre
   DateTime centre;

  //Important because this is what really defines the window range:
  //   this sample and everything 30s prior (or as determined by the InWindow predicate)
   DateTime last;  

   //for fun, because once we have the others, these are easy and fast to do at the same time
   double sum;
   int count;
   double avg;
}

// we also want to define our window range
// For this example, the head of the queue is still part of the range if it's within 30 seconds of the current sample
Func<Data, Data, bool> InWindow = (head, cur) => (head.Time.AddSeconds(30) >= cur.Time);

// and a place to accumulate our buffer (hurray for closures!)
var accBuffer = new Queue<Data>();

// now get the data
IEnumerable<Data> BufferData = ...;

// let's get to it!
var results = BufferData.Scan(new Result() {min = double.MaxValue, max = double.MinValue}, 
(acc, data) => {
    //Use flags to avoid iterating the queue if possible
    bool minmaxValid = true;

    while (accBuffer.Count > 0 && !InWindow(accBuffer.Peek(), data)
    {
       var old = accBuffer.Dequeue();
       acc.sum -= old.Value;
       acc.count--;

       //once an old min or max falls out of the window, we'll have to re-check the entire window :(
       if (old.Value == acc.min) minmaxValid = false;
       if (old.Value == acc.max) minmaxValid = false;
    }

    accBuffer.Enqueue(data);
    acc.count++;
    acc.sum += data.Value;

    acc.first = accBuffer.Peek().Time;
    acc.last = data.Time;
    acc.centre = acc.First.AddTicks( (new TimeSpan(data.Time- acc.first)).Ticks / 2);

    if (minmaxValid && data.Value < acc.min) acc.min = data.Value;
    if (minmaxValid && data.Value > acc.max) acc.max = data.Value;      

    // have to check the whole queue :(
    if (!minValid || !maxValid)
    {
        acc.min = double.MaxValue;
        acc.max = double.MinValue;
        //could use accBuffer.Max() and accBuffer.Min, but this avoids iterating the queue twice
        foreach (var d in accBuffer)
        {
           if (d.Value < acc.min) acc.min = d.Value;
           if (d.Value > acc.max) acc.max = d.Value;
        }
    }

    acc.avg = acc.sum / acc.count; 
});
```

What makes this solution special is that it's **highly** efficient. It's not quite O(n) — but it's very close!

The remaining snag to reaching a O(n) goal is the need to iterate the window queue when (and only when) a max or min value falls out of the window. I don't think it will be possible to eliminate this entirely, but I feel like there's still room for improvement here, if you can find a way to avoid that. Depending on the number of elements you need to keep and relative size of each element, you may actually do better by using some kind of sorting algorithm... but I doubt it. Unlike sum, count, and average, min and max are just hard to be efficient with in this situation.

---

Finally, I was not aware at first, but thanks to @Enigmativity's answer I now see that the Scan() operator I'm using is now incorporated into [an MS-maintained library](https://rx.codeplex.com/). It's pretty much a drop-in replacement to use that instead of MoreLINQ via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/)... the code I posted here doesn't really change at all, just get the correct `using` directives into the file.

Hmm... and as I check this, MoreLINQ was updated more recently anyway, so maybe it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the desired output completely, but here is my shot at it.

```
// Some mock data...
var data = new List<Sample>
{
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  1, 00), Value = 10 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  2, 00), Value = 11 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  2, 20), Value = 17 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  2, 30), Value = 13 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  3, 00), Value = 18 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  3, 10), Value = 12 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  4, 00), Value = 19 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  4, 25), Value = 12 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  4, 55), Value = 11 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  5, 00), Value = 12 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  6, 00), Value = 14 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  8, 03), Value = 13 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  8, 44), Value = 17 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0,  9, 01), Value = 18 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 10, 32), Value = 19 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 10, 54), Value = 15 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 11, 00), Value = 10 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 11, 05), Value = 16 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 11, 10), Value = 14 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 11, 13), Value = 16 },
    new Sample { Time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 11, 32), Value = 15 },
};

// The code...
var range = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30);

var results = data
    .Select(sample => new
    {
        Time = sample.Time,
        Set = data.Where(relatedSample => relatedSample.Time >= (sample.Time - range) && relatedSample.Time <= (sample.Time + range))
                    .Select(relatedSample => relatedSample.Value)
    })
    .Select(stat => new
    {
        Time = stat.Time,
        Avg = stat.Set.Average(),
        Min = stat.Set.Min(),
        Max = stat.Set.Max(),
        Count = stat.Set.Count()
    });
```

This will return an enumerable that has each sample, plus the min, max, avg and sample count for the 30 seconds before and after. It probably isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it is pretty straightforward. It retrieves the "window" of samples to an interim list, then performs the stats on that. So at least it's not running against the entire list more than once for each sample. It could definitely add up of there are a lot of samples in each window though.

Comment: _"at least it's not running against the entire list more than once for each sample"_ -- running against the entire list once for each sample is already bad enough, i.e. O(n^2).